# How to use composite key as id in spring redis entity as equivalent to @embedded id

Tags: java, redis, key, composite, spring-data-redis

I am using a spring data redis repository for retrieval and persistence into Redis. But I need the id to be composite of 2 fields.
How can this be achieved? Is there any way equivalent to @EmbeddedId?